# App size with use cases in between view-model and repository?

Tags: android, mvvm, software-design, clean-architecture

This is more of a software designing question than a code part of it.
I see there is a concept of having use cases/ inter-actors between viewmodel and data layer in Android MVVM with Clean Software Design. Following this, it creates a lot of use case classes in large production app. So my question is won't it dramatically increase an App size?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. When separating concerns - which is applied quite strictly in Clean Architecture - you have your code split into more classes and you will especially have more DTOs as you will convert data between the layers probably even more often than in other architecture patterns.

This might indeed increase the App size but I doubt that a few more components and data types will significantly increase the size of a "large production App". And even if there is a measurable increase in Apps size the question would be: Isn't it worth it compared to the benefits of significant higher changeability and maintainability of your code base?